# Is there a Tomboy fork which allows embedding images (or files)?

Tags: software-recommendation, tomboy

Is there an application that works exactly like Tomboy which allows you to embed images (or files)into the notes? Not links to the images, but actually in the note itself.

Comment: Are you satisfied with a fork only or any similar application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a fork of Tomboy that will enable you to insert images.

However, if you are looking for a similar note-keeping software then can I recommend [KeepNote](http://keepnote.org/).  This will work on Ubuntu as well as Windows.

Here is a screen-shot - note the ability to embed images directly into the note.

[image]

Comment: Wow!  This is great. Pretty much what I was looking for. It very much reminds me of the old Palm application NoteStudio. Now if someone could make an Android app for this it would be absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [The Board](http://live.gnome.org/TheBoardProject) is what you’re looking for, although not exactly a TomBoy replacement…

Answer (score 0):

## [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/) [image: Install zim]

Zim is an alternate personal wiki tool, allows images to be inserted, using the attach option from the menu or toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

tomboy does not allow to insert images, but there is and add-in for inserting latex equations. With keepnote you can insert images, but you can not write equations.